# Flutter : How to read data from firestore from two collections using matching id and index

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-listview

I have two screens, 1st the `ViewStudent` screen has basic data about a student. I am displaying the data inside a ListView builder. Each item inside the ListView builder has an on-tap function that goes to another screen, `StudentDetails`. I am able to read data from the firestore collection named 'student'. There is another collection named 'currentRecord' where I am adding the id from the 'student' collection as a reference.
When a user clicks on the `ViewStudent` Listview builder item, it needs to read data from the 'currentRecord' collection according to the index and display that data inside the '`StudentDetails`' screen. FYI I am using Getx.

1. Method to Read data from 'student' collection.

```
    Stream<List<StudentModel>> getAllStudents() => _firestore
          .collection(FirestoreConstants.pathUserCollection)
          .doc(_firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid)
          .collection(FirestoreConstants.pathStudentCollection)
          .orderBy(FirestoreConstants.studentName)
          .snapshots()
          .map((query) =>
              query.docs.map((e) => StudentModel.fromSnapshot(e)).toList());
```

2. Method to read data from 'currentRecord' collection.

```
    Stream<List<CurrentHifzRecordModel>> getCurrentRecords() {
        var studentId = _firestore
            .collection(FirestoreConstants.pathUserCollection)
            .doc(_firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid)
            .collection(FirestoreConstants.pathStudentCollection)
            .doc('documentId')
            .get();
        return _firestore
            .collection(FirestoreConstants.pathUserCollection)
            .doc(_firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid)
            .collection(FirestoreConstants.pathCurrentRDCollection)
            .where(FirestoreConstants.studentId, isEqualTo: studentId)
            .snapshots()
            .map((query) => query.docs
                .map((e) => CurrentHifzRecordModel.fromSnapshot(e))
                .toList());
```

3. Displaying data from 'student' collection in `ViewStudent` screen.

```
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: customAppBar('Students', context),
          body: Obx(
            () {
              return ListView.separated(
                itemCount: controller.students.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return GFListTile(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                    avatar: GFAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: AppColors.indyBlue,
                      size: GFSize.SMALL,
                      child: Text(
                        controller.students[index].studentName![0],
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: Sizes.dimen_22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                    titleText:
                        '${controller.students[index].studentName!} ${controller.students[index].fatherName!} ${controller.students[index].surname!}',
                    subTitleText:
                        '${controller.students[index].studentClass!}  Division: ${controller.students[index].classDivision}',
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.toNamed(Routes.studentDetails);
                    },
                  );
                },
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                    const Divider(),
              );
            },
          ),
```

4. Trying to display data from 'currentRecord' collection to StudentDetail screen based on index from ViewStudent screen on click on individual item.

```
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        //var data = Get.arguments;
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: customAppBar('Student Details', context),
            body: ListView.separated(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final record = controller.currentRecord[index];
                final student = controller.students
                    .where(
                        (value) => value.documentReference!.id == record.studentId)
                    .toList();
                return Column(
                  children: student.map((e) {
                    if (student.isEmpty) {
                      Get.snackbar('Error', 'No Data to show');
                    }
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        GFListTile(
                          titleText: e.studentId,
                        ),
                        GFListTile(
                          titleText: '${controller.currentRecord[index].studentId}',
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                );
              },
              itemCount: controller.currentRecord.length,
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                  const Divider(),
            ));
      }.
```

I am also adding my firebase const file that I have used for the whole application.

```
class FirestoreConstants {
  static const pathUserCollection = "users";
  static const pathStudentCollection = "student";
  static const pathCurrentRDCollection = "currentRecord";
  static const name = "name";
  static const uid = "uid";
  static const phone = "phone";
  static const email = "email";
  static const studentName = "studentName";
  static const fatherName = " fatherName";
  static const surname = "surname";
  static const studentClass = "studentClass";
  static const classDivision = "classDivision";
  static const itsNumber = "itsNumber";
  static const mobileNumber = "mobileNumber";
  static const createdOn = "createdOn";
  static const createdBy = "createdBy";
  static const createdById = "createdById";
  static const studentId = "studentId";
  static const currentJuz = "currentJuz";
  static const currentAyat = "currentAyat";
  static const currentSurah = "currentSurah";
}
```

The issue is the screen is blank and it is not displaying any error no any data. Please help me out with the issue to solve. I request you to give me a working code. Thanks.

[image: 'user' collection]

[image: 'student' collection].
[image: 'currentRecord' collection]

Comment: Can you also share the FirebaseConsts properties that are used in the code?

Comment: @SreelalTS check the answer to the question I posted, feel free to comment on it.

Answer (score 1):

So I solved my own problem for now. But I am not sure it is the right way to do it.
Step 1: Change the function for getting the record to QuerySnapshot using stream and pass an id variable.

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getRecords(String id) {
    return _firestore
        .collection(FirestoreConstants.pathUserCollection)
        .doc(_firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid)
        .collection(FirestoreConstants.pathCurrentRDCollection)
        .where(FirestoreConstants.studentId, isEqualTo: id)
        .snapshots();
   }
```

I am passing an argument when going to the next screen with studentId that I am getting from index when list item is clicked.

```
onTap: (){
 Map<String, dynamic> data() => {
                          FirestoreConstants.studentId:
                              controller.students[index].studentId,
                          FirestoreConstants.studentName:
                              controller.students[index].studentName!,
                          FirestoreConstants.fatherName:
                              controller.students[index].fatherName!,};
                    Get.toNamed(Routes.studentDetails, arguments: data());
}
```

student details screen looks like this using a stream builder to get compare id and get data from firestore.

```
class StudentDetails extends GetView<ViewStudentController> {
  const StudentDetails({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var data = Get.arguments;
    return Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: controller.getRecords(data[FirestoreConstants.studentId]),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('Something went wrong');
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Text('Loading');
        }
        return ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: snapshot.data!.docs
              .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                Map<String, dynamic> data =
                    document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(data[FirestoreConstants.studentId]),
                  subtitle: Text(data[FirestoreConstants.currentJuz]),
                );
              })
              .toList()
              .cast(),
        );
      },
    ));
  }
}
```